# Trying to restart automatically Node.js server when it's crashed

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, forever

I was trying to use forever in my Node.js server because i need to restart automatically the server when it crashes. But when i have an error and my server is crashed  the module forever doesn't make nothing and it doesn´t restart it again. It´s possible that i may have misunderstood the functionality  of forever but i expected that server would be restarted automatically. I have followed this instructions:

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

On my server side i have an api that provide me access to a mysql database. I want to restart the server automatically when i have an error on my api and server is crashed. I have introduced some intentional error in a query to prove the functionallity of forever, but i have the next message on the console log when i list the processes:

**C:\Users\jtapia\iter04_8>forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command                            script
        forever pid  id logfile                           uptime
data:    [0] 5f4D "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\jtapia\iter04_8\se
rver.js 5308    3264    C:\Users\jtapia.forever\5f4D.log STOPPED**

Am i wrong or i am doing something wrong? i would be very gratefull if someone could help me with this topic. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Does that script even work on windows? Supervising works only on *nix systems which implement POSIX process control. Don't you need the fork of forever that works on Windows?

Comment: I have answer you in a new comment :)